# Keras: How to save models or weights?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, save

I am sorry if this question seems pretty straight forward. But reading the Keras save and restore help page :

https://www.tensorflow.org/beta/tutorials/keras/save_and_restore_models

I do not understand how to use the "ModelCheckpoint" for saving during training. The help file mentions it should give 3 files, I see only one, MODEL.ckpt.

Here is my code:

```
checkpoint_dir = FolderName + "/tmp/model.ckpt"
cp_callback = k.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(checkpoint_dir,verbose=1,save_weights_only=True)    
parallel_model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),loss=my_cost_MSE, metrics=['accuracy])
    parallel _model.fit(image, annotation, epochs=epoch, 
    batch_size=batch_size, steps_per_epoch=10,
                                 validation_data=(image_val,annotation_val),validation_steps=num_batch_val,callbacks=callbacks_list)
```

Also, when I want to load the weights after training with:

```
model = k.models.load_model(file_checkpoint)
```

I get the error:

```
"raise ValueError('Unknown ' + printable_module_name + ':' + object_name) 
ValueError: Unknown loss function:my_cost_MSE"
```

my-cost_MSE is my cost function that is used in the training.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, it looks like you are using the `tf.keras` (from tensorflow) implementation rather than `keras` (from the keras-team/keras repo). In this case, as stated in the [tf.keras guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras#import_tfkeras) :

> When saving a model's weights, tf.keras defaults to the checkpoint
>   format. Pass save_format='h5' to use HDF5.

On the other hand, note that adding the callback `ModelCheckpoint` is, usually, roughly equivalent to call `model.save(...)` at the end of each epoch, so that's why you should expect three files to be saved (according to the [checkpoint format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/checkpoints)).

The reason it's not doing so is because, by using the option `save_weights_only=True`, you are saving just the weights. Roughly equivalent to replace the call to `model.save` for `model.save_weights` at the end of each epoch. Hence, the only file that's being saved is the one with the weights.

From here, you can proceed in two different ways:

### Storing just the weights

You need your model (the structure, let's say) to be loaded beforehand and then call `model.load_weights` instead of `keras.models.load_model`:

```py
model = MyModel(...)  # Your model definition as used in training
model.load_weights(file_checkpoint)
```

Note that in this case, you won't have problems with custom definitions (`my_cost_MSE`) since you are just loading model weights.

### Storing the whole model

Another way to proceed is to store the whole model and load it accordingly:

```py
cp_callback = k.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint(
    checkpoint_dir,verbose=1,
    save_weights_only=False
)    
parallel_model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=learning_rate),
    loss=my_cost_MSE,
    metrics=['accuracy']
)

model.fit(..., callbacks=[cp_callback])
```

Then you could load it by:

```py
model = k.models.load_model(file_checkpoint, custom_objects={"my_cost_MSE": my_cost_MSE})
```

Note that in this latter case, you need to specify `custom_objects` since its definition is needed to deserialize the model.

Answer (score 0):

`keras` has a `save` command. It saves all the details needed to rebuild the model.

(from the [keras docs](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-save-a-keras-model))

```
from keras.models import load_model
model.save('my_model.h5')  # creates a HDF5 file 'my_model.h5'
del model  # deletes the existing model

# returns am identical compiled model
model = load_model('my_model.h5')
```

Comment: how do I apply this during training? I saw this on the other pages asking about saving, but in the model.fit it will not work.